# Strange error, Exception Value: type object has no attribute 'DoesNoExist'

Tags: python, django

I have this code. and i dont understand why it shows the error that i seem not to put the DoesNotExist handler when is already there.... and shows me this error:

> AttributeError at /hotel/edit/hotel-riodssdfsdf-google-facebook-351/
>
> type object 'hotel' has no attribute 'DoesNoExist'
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:
>     http::9000/hotel/edit/hotel-riodssdfsdf-google-facebook-351/ Django
>   Version:  1.6.2 Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:
>
> type object 'hotel' has no attribute 'DoesNoExist'
>
> Exception Location:   views.py in update, line 171

LINE 171 is correct....: except hotel.DoesNoExist:

```
if 'member_id' not in request.session:

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')

else:

    if request.POST:

        try:

            hotelObject = hotel.objects.get(slug=slug)

            form = UpdateHotelForm(request.POST, instance=hotelObject)

            if form.is_valid():

                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                slug_name = slugify(name + ' ' + str(now.microsecond))

                hotels = hotel.objects.get(
                    id=hotelObject.id,
                    publisher=request.session['member_id'])

                hotels.name = name

                hotels.slug = slug_name

                hotels.save()

                args = {}

                args.update(csrf(request))

                args['form'] = form
                args['message'] = False
                args['name'] = hotelObject.name

                return HttpResponseRedirect('/hotel/edit/' + slug_name)

            else:

                args = {}

                args.update(csrf(request))

                args['form'] = form
                args['message'] = True
                args['name'] = hotelObject.name

                return render_to_response('hotel/edit_hotel.html', args)

        except hotel.DoesNoExist:

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/hotel/')
    else:

        try:

            hotelObject = hotel.objects.get(slug=slug)

            form = UpdateHotelForm(request.POST, instance=hotelObject)

            form = UpdateHotelForm(instance=hotelObject)

            args = {}

            args.update(csrf(request))

            args['form'] = form
            args['name'] = hotelObject.name

            return render_to_response('hotel/edit_hotel.html', args)

        except hotel.DoesNoExist:

           return HttpResponseRedirect('/hotel/')
```

Comment: where is `hotel.DoesNoExist` defined?

Comment: Aren't you actually referring to DoesNotExist instead of DoesNoExist?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the question, but you should name your Django models in CamelCase (ie. `Hotel` instead of `hotel`).

Comment: You may also want to use `login_required`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct is hotel.DoesNotExist not hotel.DoesNoExiste a

Comment: Thank you.. I never checked the spell twice. sorry for bothering with this question.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `DoesNotExist` as `DoesNoExist`. Change it to:

```
except hotel.DoesNotExist:
```